# What hardware can I use to run digital signage on my 3 TV video wall?

Tags: video, television, 4k, nuc

I need to setup a video wall that's composed of 3 horizontally aligned TVs (1 x 3). The 3 TVs are 4k (3840 x 2160), use HDMI and are not daisy-chainable. I'm looking for a computer/hardware that could run digital signage across my 3 televisions. I considered something like an Intel NUC, however it does not support 3 x 4k 60Hz TVs. It only need to be able to show very big pictures and videos.

Comment: With some adapters, I think a modern video card should do the trick.

Comment: So you are suggesting I build the computer myself?

Comment: That is an option, but not neccessary. Some prebuilts do have good graphics cards for big displays. Do mind that is should have 3 hdmi's, but with adapters you can also count DisplayPorts as hdmi's.

Comment: You can find and purchase a variety of GPU's which will handle 3 HDMI connectors or 3 displayport plugs and use adapters.  Some even have 4.  Said video card will plug into any computer that has a pcie x16 slot.